# Reply to a command only if it is from a certain user ID with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm really new with discord.py, so this may look terrible.

The question is: what am I doing wrong in this piece of code:

```
    @bot.command()
async def activity(ctx, par1):
    if message.author == 272467367991312394:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.competing, name=par1))
    else:
        return
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check for `ctx.message.author.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ctx.message.author.id == 272467367991312394:
```

To:

```
if ctx.author.id == 272467367991312394:
```

Because you use ctx you do not also have to use "message"
If you did not use ctx, and you would have done message as parameter you could have done mesesage.author.id, but that is not the case here.

Hope I helped you, and if this answer worked, I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as the one that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
@bot.command()
async def activity(ctx, par1):
    if ctx.message.author.id == 272467367991312394:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.competing, name=par1))
    else:
        await ctx.send("No tenes permisos para ejecutar este comando!")
```